# Elementary set theory involving partition

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Hello could someone verify and correct if necessary my answer to the following question :

**Is the given collection P a partition of the set A?Justify your answers.**

**With:** $A=\Bbb{R}$ and $P=${$[n,n+1)$ : $ n\in \Bbb{Z}$} where [n,n+1) is the half-open interval.

**Then my attempt:**

For the collection of nonempty subsets P to be a partition of A the following conditions must hold true.

**(i)For all elements $a\in A$ , there exists a set $S \in P$ such that    $a \in S$ .**

[case : $a \in \Bbb{Z}$]

- For every $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ one can find a $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that
  $n\le a\lt n+1$, simply by setting $n=a$.
        In interval and set    notations we have the following    $S:=$    $[a,a+1)$= {r $\in \Bbb{R}:a\le r \lt a+1$}.

  By the defintion of P,this half-open interval S is an element of the
  collection P  that contains $a$.

[case : $a \notin \Bbb{Z}$]

- Therefore $a \in \Bbb{R}$ \ $\Bbb{Z}$ or equivalently $a$ has numbers
  following the decimal point that are not all zero.Suppose $a_{rounded}$ is the next lowest integer to which we can round $a$,then $a_{rounded}\le a \lt a_{rounded}+1$ is assured.Letting $S:=[a_{rounded},a_{rouned}+1)=$ {$r \in \Bbb{R} :a_{rounded}    \le r \lt a_{rounded}+1 $}.

  By the defintion of P,this half-open    interval S is an element of
  the collection P that contains $a_{rounded}$.

Therefore condition (i) has been met for all possible elements of A.

**(ii) For all $S,T\in P$**, if $S \neq T$ then $S \cap T = \varnothing$.

Let $m,n \in \Bbb{Z}$ where $m \neq n$.Further define $S:=[n,n+1)$ and 
$T:=[m,m+1)$.

[case : $m\gt n$]

- If $m\gt n $ then $m\ge n+1$ and hence $n+1 \le m \lt n+2 \le m+1$ .Also $T=[m,m+1)$={$r\in \Bbb{R} : n+1\le
     r \lt m+1$}$=[n+1,m+1)$.

  Consequently with $S:=[n,n+1)$ and $T=[n+1,m+1)$ the following result
  is assured $S \cap T=\varnothing$

[case : $m\lt n$]

- If $m \lt n$ then $m\le n-1$ and hence $m \le n-1 \lt m+1 \le n$. Also $T=[m,m+1)$={$r\in \Bbb{R} : m\le
     r \lt n$}$=[m,n)$.

  Consequently with $S:=[n,n+1)$ and $T=[m,n)$ the following result
  is assured $S \cap T=\varnothing$

Therefore the second condtion (ii) holds true for any pair $S,T \in P$.

Since both conditions have been verified,the collection P is a valid partition of set A.

Does this make sense?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perfect proof!!

Comment: honest or jokeing?

Comment: Your proof should be much worse for jokes about it to be funny! Why would I post an unfunny joke on a serious site?

Comment: oh ok thank you..i honestly do not know.!!..gotta hate textbooks witout answers!!

Comment: If you start from the premises and reached the conclusion without cheating, that's it!